# convert int to char* in standard C (without itoa)

Tags: c, char, int, itoa

I have declared and initialized two variables as shown below:

```
int a=5;
char* str;
str = (char*)calloc(255, sizeof(char));
```

I want to convert the int to char* in standard C. I cannot use any conversion function from C++ such itoa.

I am using Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: @rogelware: `itoa` is not a standard C function and is not available on Linux.

Comment: What do you mean by standard C function? It's is present at <stdlib.h>.. Do you mean you can't use includes? (just checked, yes, itoa is not standard)

Comment: @rogelware: it's not present in `<stdlib.h>` on all platforms and it's not present in the C standard.

Comment: Checking the reference, the function to be used is `sprintf` like [ThiefMaster](http://stackoverflow.com/users/298479/thiefmaster) suggested. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all, `itoa` is not a C++ thing.

You can simply use `sprintf`:

```
sprintf(str, "%d", a)
```

In a real application you'll want to use `snprintf` though to remove the risk of a buffer overflow:

```
str = malloc(16);
snprintf(str, 16, "%d", a);
```

And 15 characters are way enough to store an integer.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is per definition equal to 1, and `calloc` is overkill. Also, casting the result from `calloc` is useless. Just `str = malloc(BUFSIZE)` would suffice.

Comment: Yeah, just copied it from his question. However, there are many people who always use calloc instead of malloc even if one of the arguments is `1` since it nulls the memory and saves the hassle of doing a memset after the allocation.

Comment: fair enough, but given that you were making corrections already, I though you might want to add these in as well :)

Comment: 15 characters is not enough for long on most 64-bit platforms, it might be good to drop the habit of thinking long == int.

Comment: If it's `int`, 15 chars should be sufficient. But you are right if it can be a `long` or `long long`. Then he needs a 21+ char buffer.

Comment: The answer is correct, but I wouldn't mention the existence of `sprintf`. It's good that you suggest `snprintf` for a real application, but why not use it for "unreal" ones as well?

Comment: snprintf is only C99, not ANSI C, `str = malloc(BUFSIZE)` is wrong, right is `str = malloc(BUFSIZ)`

Comment: @user411313: 1) The OP did not ask for ANSI C. 2) `BUFSIZE` is perfectly fine when defined by yourself - and I did define `BUFSIZE` in my answer. 3) Please get a nickname, the default user12345 nicks are annoying.

Comment: ANSI C is^H^Hwas C99. Now it's C11.